# What are the possible values of _POSIX_TIMERS?

Tags: c, posix, posix-api

The [posixoptions manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/7/posixoptions) shows that the following macros can be used to determine the degree of a host's support for the posix timers API:

- `_POSIX_TIMERS`
- `_POSIX_CPUTIME`
- `_POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME`
- `_POSIX_CLOCK_SELECTION`
- `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK`

On my dev system (Ubuntu-based Linux distro, using gcc 7.5.0), `_POSIX_TIMERS` evaluates to `200809`, `_POSIX_CPUTIME` to `0`, and `_POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME` to `0`.

I have been searching for more information on these macros, but can't seem to find the needed information. I would like to know where they are defined (in a header file? or "magically" by the compiler?), and what the possible values of `_POSIX_TIMERS` are.

However, I did run across some C code which compared `_POSIX_TIMERS` to another constant starting with `2012`. So obviously various different values must be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX definition (2018 edition) says that:

> `_POSIX_TIMERS`
>
> The implementation supports timers. This symbol shall always be set to the value `200809L`.

It's defined in [the `<unistd.h>` header](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html).

Comment: It's probably not actually in `unistd.h`, though, but rather in another file that it includes. On my system, it's actually in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix_opt.h`.

Answer (score 2):

When defined (by the implementation—not you), these *feature test macros* expand to an integral constant of type `long`.

If undefined or `0L`, the feature is not supported.
Otherwise the value is `YYYYMM`, indicating the year and month of the respective standard's publication.

The idea is that developers can use conditional compilation to test for the presence of a particular feature, in a particular version or set of versions. And to make it future-proof, so developers can express "I need at least the 2012 version of this feature, 2008 is not enough".